# Error using "cp" to copy files to an external disk

Tags: bash, external-hdd, cp, exfat

I have a 2TB external HDD formatted with exFat that I use to share very large files (>10GB) among Ubuntu, Windows 7 and MacOS.

I am trying to copy the whole content of a directory using

```
sudo cp -r . /media/user/WD2TB
```

But I am getting the following output to what seems to be a very long filename

```
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/media/user/WD2TB/./Pictures/2013/Travel/2013-05-01_05:29_1367382554_Aaaaaaa_Bbbbbbb_Cccccccccc.JPG.xmp’: No such file or directory
```

Anyone knows why is this happening?

Answer (score 4):

The filename contains a colon character `:` which is illegal in Windows and therefore likely not supported by the ExFAT filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Very long filenames often cause problems. You may try to copy the files with Rsync, however it's not guaranteed that the filesystem will actually support the long names.

```
sudo rsync -rv . /media/WD2TB
```

Comment: I believe that the long filename might be a red herring. The cp command should work, do you know why it's not working?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not sure at all about why it doesn't work. There could be different reasons.